# Linked list program for student average

Tags: c, linked-list

I am new to C programming especially linked list. Can someone please help me with my code? When I compile the program there is no error but when I try to run the program its output is wrong. I don't know if the storing is wrong or the printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* self-referential structure */
struct listNode {
    char name[80];
    char subject[80]; /* each listNode contains a character */
    float unit;
    float grade;
    struct listNode *nextPtr; /* pointer to next node */
}; /* end structure listNode */

typedef struct listNode ListNode; /* synonym for struct listNode */
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; /* synonym for ListNode* */

/* prototypes */
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char SUB[80], float grade, float unit, char NAME[80]);
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr);
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr, ListNodePtr *sPtr);
void instructions(void);

int main(void)
{
    ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL; /* initially there are no nodes */
    int choice; /* user's choice */
    float grades, units;
    char subn[80], stdn[80];
    int i, j, std = 0, sub = 0;

    instructions(); /* display the menu */
    printf("? ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    /* loop while user does not choose 3 */
    while (choice != 3) {
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: /* input data */
            printf("Number of Students: (at least 5 students)\n");
            scanf("%d", &std);

            for (i = 0; i < std; i++) {
                printf("\nStudent name: ");
                scanf("%s", &stdn);
                printf("How many subjects?\n");
                scanf("%d", &sub);
                for (j = 0; j < sub; j++) {
                    printf("\nSub­ject: ");
                    scanf("%s", &subn);
                    printf("Units­: ");
                    scanf("%f", &units);
                    printf("Final­ Grade: ");
                    scanf("%f", &grades);
                    insert(&startPtr, subn, grades, units, stdn);
                }
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            printList(startPtr, &startPtr);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.\n\n");
            instructions();
            break;
        } /* end switch */

        printf("\n\n? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    } /* end while */

    printf("End of run.\n");
    return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
} /* end main */

/* display program instructions to user */
void instructions(void)
{
    printf("Enter your choice:\n"
        " 1 to Input Student Data.\n"
        " 2 to Display Student Data.\n"
        " 3 to end.\n");
} /* end function instructions */

/* for series */
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char SUB[80], float grade, float unit, char NAME[80])
{
    ListNodePtr newPtr; /* pointer to new node */
    ListNodePtr previousPtr; /* pointer to previous node in list */
    ListNodePtr currentPtr; /* pointer to current node in list */

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); /* create node */

    if (newPtr != NULL) { /* is space available */
        strcpy(newPtr->na­me, NAME);
        strcpy(newPtr->subject, SUB); /* place value in node */
        newPtr->grade = grade;
        newPtr->unit = unit;
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; /* node does not link to another node */

        previousPtr = NULL;
        currentPtr = *sPtr;

        /* insert new node at beginning of list */
        if (previousPtr == NULL) {
            newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
            *sPtr = newPtr;
        } /* end if */
        else { /* insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr */
            previousPtr->nex­tPtr = newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
        } /* end else */
    } /* end if */
    else {
        printf("Student data not inserted. No memory available.\n");
    } /* end else */
} /* end function insert */

int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{
    return sPtr == NULL;
} /* end function isEmpty */

/* Print the list */
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr, ListNodePtr *sPtr)
{
    float total = 0.00, total2 = 0.00;
    /* if list is empty */
    if (currentPtr == NULL) {
        printf("List is empty.\n\n");
    } /* end if */
    else {
        printf("\n");
        printf("%-20s\t%s\­t%s\n", "Subject", "Units", "Final Grade");
        /* while not the end of the list */
        while (currentPtr != NULL) {
            printf("Student­ Name: %s\n", currentPtr->name);
            printf("%-20s\t%.2f\t%.2f\n­", currentPtr->subject, ­ currentPtr->unit, currentPtr->grade);
            total += currentPtr->unit;
            total2 += currentPtr->unit*cur­rentPtr->grade;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        } /* end while */

        printf("\nWeight:­ %.2f", total2 / total);
        printf("\n///////­/////////////////////­/////////////////////­///");
    } /* end else */
} /* end function printList */
```

Comment: The easiest way to post code is to indent every line by four characters, which should be easy to do in your IDE, and then don't include blank lines between every line. However this question isn't a great fit for StackOverflow: you're asking us to work out why your program isn't working without telling us expected input and outputs, why it doesn't work. Even so 'debug my program' isn't really specific enough for here anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too not-formatted; didn't read.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow. will do better next time. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Heading

Hi,
I have not looked thoroughly in the code . But , in a quick look I spotted the following basic problem

nextPtr should be a pointer, you are creating an instance and copying the contents of the next structure. This is not efficient.
I will declare it as below

struct listNode *nextPtr; / pointer to next node */

Again , I will change the followingtypedef ListNode ListNodePtr; 
typedef ListNode ListNodePtr;

to 
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr;

Try to restructure your code with this, and see how it goes. If not helping, I can have a detailed look in the evening.

Comment: Thank you very much. i did not check stackoverflow because i solved it already but found out that you answered the code that solved it.